Bazel architecture dependent module
Is there a way to have architecture dependent modules in bazel, like do the following (pseudocode):
if x86:
 bazel_dep(name = "ModuleA", version="1.0")
else if arm:
 bazel_dep(name = "ModuleB", version="0.5")

So far - all the solutions I have seen are WORKSPACE oriented, not Bazelmod - and I don't see anything in the docs related - or I am not searching for the right thing.
Much appreciated!
